# jsoncpp: access a JSON object by name, return mutable reference, don't create an object if not found

Tags: c++, jsoncpp

I'm using jsoncpp to manipulate a JSON string. Having parsed the string into a Json::Value I want to access and possibly change one of the nested objects if it exists. If the nested object doesn't exist I don't want it to be created.

Looking at the [json documentation](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_value.html) it seems that the only way to return a  reference to an object is via operator[].

```
Value& operator[] (const char *key)
```

Access an object value by name, create a null member if it does not exist.

```
const Value& operator[] (const char *key) const
```

Access an object value by name, returns null if there is no member with that name.

I need something that combines the semantics of both of these: I want a mutable reference, but one that doesn't involve creating an object if it doesn't already exist. (I understand why the Json::Value interface is designed the way it is: returning a mutable reference would expose its internal null object.)

The only clean way I can see is to use Json::Value::isMember to determine whether the object exists, and then use Value& operator[] to access the object. But this involves two O( log N ) lookups instead of one, which I might want to avoid.

Short of an ugly const_cast, is there any sensible way of doing what I want?

Comment: Doing that would leave you with mutable references to `Json::Value::null`, which is constant, and that would not at all be sensible. You could check with `isMember` if a member exists before accessing it, although that'll incur the runtime overhead of an additional lookup.

Comment: The [documentation has moved](http://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/). In fact, so has [the project](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/).

Answer (score 2):

Wintermute is correct.

Think about your use-case. Hopefully, it fits one of these:

- If existence is uncommon, then the second look-up is only a small cost.
- If existence is common, then use `operator[]()` or `get()`, followed by [`removeMember()`](http://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/class_json_1_1_value.html#a708e599489adf30d65bf85a8ee16e6fb) when you need to delete the object you have created.

But if your proposed feature is very important to you, we could add a new method:

  `bool Value::get(char const* key, Value** gotten);`

That would cause your own `Value*` to point into the member, but only if it exists. (I guess we could even drop the `bool` and simply set `*gotten = nullptr` when not found.) If this interests you, [file an issue](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/issues/new).

Comment: Thanks. That doesn't seem to fit well with the current set of methods though, and I think I'd prefer something like Value& get (const char *key, Value &defaultValue)   We're using jsoncpp in an embedded system, rebuilding jsoncpp would involve some logistics, and profiling indicates that we don't have a performance issue at the moment, so we have no urgent need for a change at the moment.

Comment: @SimonElliott, We cannot use a sentinel for the Value because the sentinel might be a valid result. Thus, you need at least one extra bit of information in addition to the returned Value. We could discuss this more in GitHub if you [open an issue](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/issues/new).